presuppositional apologetics
Well, recently I've been trying to better understand the different apologetics approaches, but am having a hard time understanding the presuppositional apologetics standpoint. I've heard several apologists claim that the book of Acts shows the apostles using evidentialist apologetics, and that even Jesus used a form of evidence based apologetics by using miracles to persuade people of his divinity. They use this as an argument against presuppositionalism. I was simply wondering how someone of the presuppositonal persuasion would respond to this argument.

Is it either/or? For example, Jesus also took into account people's presuppositions in dialogues with them. With the Sadducees, his argument for the resurrection of the dead was based only on the scriptures they accepted. He challenged the Pharisees to believe in him because they believed Moses, and Moses prophesied of him. So with Paul, who tailored his testimony to the world view of his audience.
